# Solving a PDE through separation of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following *PDE*:

$$x^2u_{xx} - y^2u_{yy}-2yu_y = 0 .$$

after seperating variables, I obtain after separating variables, I obtain $$\frac{x^2}{\phi} \phi '' = - \lambda ,$$ and  $$\frac{y^2}{g} g ''  -\frac{2y}{g} g' = -\lambda,$$  where $u(x,y) = \phi(x)g(y)$ and $\lambda$ is the separation constant. How should I proceed?

Comment: This are both Cauchy-Euler equations, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation

Comment: Actually you should get $\dfrac{y^2}{g} g'' + \dfrac{2y}{g} g' = -\lambda$.

Answer (score 2):

It is more powerful to use the [method of characteristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) (MoC) than [separation of variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables) (SoV) for OP's problem. In this answer we give a sketched derivation of the full solution using the MoC.

1. Notice that OP's linear 2nd order PDE 
   $$x^2 u_{xx}-y^2 u_{yy}-2yu_y~=~0 $$
   is form-invariant under scalings $(x,y)\to (\lambda z, \mu y)$.
   This suggests that we should define new variables
   $$X~=~\ln|x|\quad\text{and}\quad Y~=~\ln|y|.$$
   Then OP's linear 2nd order PDE becomes a linear 2nd order PDE 
   $$u_{XX}-u_X-u_{YY}-u_Y~=~0  $$
   with constant coefficient functions.
2. If we define 
   $$ X^{\pm}~=~X\pm Y, $$
   the PDE factorizes
   $$ (4\partial_--2)\partial_+u~=~0, $$
   or equivalently,
   $$ \partial_- e^{-X^-/2}\partial_+u~=~0, $$
   with full solution
   $$u~=~ F(X^-)+ e^{X^-/2}G(X^+),$$
   where $F,G$ are arbitrary functions.
3. Going back to the original variables, the solution reads
   $$ u~=~ f(x/y) + \sqrt{\left| \frac{x}{y}\right|} g(xy), $$
   where $f,g$ are arbitrary functions. This can in turn be beautified to$^1$
   $$ u~=~ f(x/y) + x g(xy)  $$
   for arbitrary functions $f,g$. The above full solution would have been more difficult to derive using SoV.

--

$^1$ Hat tip: [Robert Israel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8508/robert-israel).

Comment: How did you know to choose $X= ln |x|$ and $Y=ln|y|$?

Comment: From the form-invariance under scaling. I updated the answer.

Comment: I don't understand. I can see why you chose to find new variables, but how did you find $X=ln|x|$?

Comment: So that $x\partial_x=\partial_X$.

Comment: A slightly nicer form, avoiding apparent problems at $x=0$, is $u = f(x/y) + x g(xy)$.

Comment: @Robert Israel: Good point!