# Solving second order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the PDE $x^2U_{xx}-2xyU_{xy}+y^2U_{yy}+xU_x + yU_y = 0.$

I thought this could be handled by a change of variables $X = ln|x|$ , $Y=ln|y|$ , but this approach gets me stuck pretty fast.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you studied techniques for solving pde's ?

Comment: Some. I've done separation of variables, method of characteristics, and change of variables, but I haven't done any fourier/laplace transformations  for PDEs yet.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1659989/11127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change of variables  $\begin{cases}
X=\ln|x|\\
Y=\ln|y|
\end{cases}$
transforms the PDE into : 
$$U_{XX}-2U_{XY}+U_{YY}=0$$
A second change of variables : 
$\begin{cases}
s=X+Y\\
t=X-Y
\end{cases}$ reduces the PDE to :
$$U_{tt}=0$$
The double integration of this very simple differential equation gives :
$$U(s,t)=f(s)t+g(s)$$
where $f$ and $g$ are any derivable functions.
Then, coming back to the preceeding variables :
$$U(X,Y)=(X-Y)f(X+Y)+g(X+Y)$$
$$U(x,y)=\ln|\frac{x}{y}| f(\ln|xy|)+g(\ln|xy|)$$
Or, on an equivalent form with any derivable functions $F$ and $G$ :
$$U(x,y)=\ln\left|\frac{x}{y}\right|\: F(xy)+G(xy)$$